# How elegantly iterate over list or dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a variable (object from database). In some cases this variable can be type of **list** and in some cases **dictionary**.

Standard for cycle if variable is **list**:

```
for value in object_values:
    self.do_something(value)
```

Standard for cycle if variable is **dictionary**:

```
for key, value in object_values.items():
    self.do_something(value)
```

I can use `instanceof()` two check the type, but then I still need two functions or `if` with two `for` cycles. I have now `if` condition which calls one of the two functions, one for iterating as list (e.g. `iterate_list()`) and the second for iterating as dictionary (e.g. `iterate_dict()`) .

**Is there any better option how elegantly and more pythonic way resolve problem that I don't know if the variable will be list or dictionary?**

Comment: second example: `for value in object_values.values():` then

Comment: Its very weird that it can return one of two things. It doesnt sound quite right to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your case, since the data is either the items or the values of the dictionary, you could use a ternary to get `values()` or just the iterable depending on the type:

```
def iterate(self,object_values):
    for value in object_values.values() if isinstance(object_values,dict) else object_values:
        self.do_something(value)
```

If you pass a `tuple`, generator or other iterable, it falls back on "standard" iteration. If you pass a dictionary (or `OrderedDict` or other), it iterates on the values.

Performance-wise, the ternary expression is evaluated only once at the start of the iteration, so it's fine.

The `isinstance` bit could even be replaced by `if hasattr(object_values,"values")` so even non-dict objects with a `values` member would match.

(Note that you should be aware of the "least atonishment" principle. Some people may expect an iteration on the keys of the dictionary when calling the method)